# Magento 2.2.6: I have an error modifying the select collection

Tags: magento2, attributes, select

I need to modify the query of the orders in the grid of the backend by representative attribute (custom attribute).

I get the following **error**:

> Item (Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document) with the same ID "2" already exists.

**DataProvider:** (applyDealerFilter() method)

```
class DataProviderCollectionFactory
{
    /** @var mixed */
    protected $_requestName;

    /** @var  CollectionModifier */
    protected $_collectionModifier;

    /** @var  PermHelper */
    protected $_permHelper;

    /** @var DealerOrderCollectionFactory  */
    protected $_dealerOrderCollectionFactory;

    /** @var DealerCustomerCollectionFactory  */
    protected $_dealerCustomerCollectionFactory;

    /** @var Scope Config  */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @param PermHelper $permHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionModifier $collectionModifier,
        PermHelper $permHelper,
        DealerCustomerCollectionFactory $dealerCustomerCollectionFactory,
        DealerOrderCollectionFactory $dealerOrderCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_collectionModifier = $collectionModifier;
        $this->_permHelper = $permHelper;
        $this->_dealerCustomerCollectionFactory = $dealerCustomerCollectionFactory;
        $this->_dealerOrderCollectionFactory = $dealerOrderCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param $requestName
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeGetReport(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        $requestName
    ){
        $this->_requestName = $requestName;
        return [$requestName];
    }

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param AbstractCollection $collection
     * @return AbstractCollection
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function afterGetReport(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        $collection
    ){
        if ($this->_permHelper->isAllowAllCustomersAndOrders()) {
            return $collection;
        }

        if (
            ($this->_collectionModifier->isOrderDataSource($this->_requestName)) &&
            $this->_permHelper->isBackendDealer()
        ){ //if order based collections
            $this->_collectionModifier->applyDealerFilter(
                $this->_permHelper->getBackendDealer()->getId(),
                $collection,
                $this->_dealerOrderCollectionFactory,
                'entity_id',
                'order_id'
            );
        } else if (
            (
                $this->_collectionModifier->isInvoiceDataSource($this->_requestName) ||
                $this->_collectionModifier->isShipmentDataSource($this->_requestName) ||
                $this->_collectionModifier->isCreditMemoDataSource($this->_requestName)
            ) &&
            $this->_permHelper->isBackendDealer()
        ) {
            $this->_collectionModifier->applyDealerFilter(
                $this->_permHelper->getBackendDealer()->getId(),
                $collection,
                $this->_dealerOrderCollectionFactory,
                'order_id',
                'order_id'
            );
        } else if (
            ($this->_collectionModifier->isCustomerDataSource($this->_requestName)) &&
            $this->_permHelper->isBackendDealer()
        ){ //if customer based collections
            $this->_collectionModifier->applyDealerFilter(
                $this->_permHelper->getBackendDealer()->getId(),
                $collection,
                $this->_dealerCustomerCollectionFactory,
                'entity_id',
                'customer_id'
            );
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

**Where the filter with joins is applied:**

```
class CollectionModifier extends \Amasty\Perm\Helper\CollectionModifier
{
    /**
     * Filter collection by dealer
     * @param $value
     * @param AbstractCollection $collection
     * @param $factory
     * @param string $primaryKey
     * @param string $foreignKey
     * @param string $filterPostfix
     * @throws \Zend_Db_Select_Exception
     */
    public function applyDealerFilter(
        $value,
        AbstractCollection $collection,
        $factory,
        $primaryKey = 'entity_id',
        $foreignKey = 'entity_id',
        $filterPostfix = '_filter'
    ){

        $collection->getSelect()->join(
            ['ce' => $collection->getTable('customer_entity')],
            'ce.email = main_table.customer_email'
        )->join(
            ['cet' => $collection->getTable('customer_entity_text')],
            'cet.entity_id = ce.entity_id'
        )->join(
            ['ea' => $collection->getTable('eav_attribute')],
            'ea.attribute_id = cet.attribute_id'
        )->where(
            'ea.attribute_code = \'mod_dealers\''
        )->where(
            'cet.value like \'%' . $value . '%\''
        );


        /**
        here I have the error ID:
          Item (Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document) with the same ID "2" already exists.
        */
        var_dump($collection->toArray()); die("stop"); 

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento can not process more than two equal fields internally.

The solution is to make a **where IN**:

```
    $collection->getSelect()->where(
        ' main_table.entity_id IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                so.entity_id
                FROM ' . $collection->getMainTable() . ' so
                INNER JOIN customer_entity ce on ce.email = so.customer_email
                INNER JOIN customer_entity_text cet on cet.entity_id = ce.entity_id
                INNER JOIN eav_attribute ea on ea.attribute_id = cet.attribute_id
                WHERE ea.attribute_code = \'mod_dealers\' 
                AND FIND_IN_SET(\'' . $value . '\', cet.value)
                )'
    );
```